# How to create controls using Sql Datasource in c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, datasource

I want to know how to create controls in Winforms using Datasource.I mean whatever fields in table that should be created as control in Form . I have seen that by drag and drop those fileds  it create control .How its working like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior that you mention can be done using he Data Source Window in Visual Studio. The following MSDN titled [Data Sources Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ckyxa83.aspx) will take you through all the steps needed to do what you want from connecting to a database to setting what controls show when you drag the data source onto the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sourcecodegenerator like [mygeneration](http://mygeneration.sourceforge.net/) 
plus a generator template for winforms.